# Book on Linear algebra/ Matrix analysis?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

guys, I plan to learn more on the linear algebra/ matrix as I am going into convex optimizations. Basicly, I many need

Matrix decomposition like SVD.
Some contents on semidefinite/definite matrix.

It'll be fantastic if there are also proofs/explanations.

Thanks.

Comment: I recommend Linear Algebra and Its Applications by Strang, and Numerical Linear Algebra by Trefethen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Matrix Analysis*, by Horn and Johnson. It is an exhaustive reference.

Comment: This book seems the right one. Also say thanks to vincent, but I may need something more than undergraduate things.

Answer (score 4):

I was literally just thinking about this a month ago.

Hoffman & Kunze's "Linear Algebra"/Stephen Friedberg's "Linear Algebra" paired with Axler's "Linear Algebra Done Right" should give you an in-depth covering of undergraduate Linear Algebra. All three of these texts contain  exercises consisting of mostly proofs, with more emphasis on the abstraction rather than numerous matrix computations (there are some exercises that allow you practice this, however).

At the moment, I am using Stephen Friedberg's "Linear Algebra" and Axler's "LADR" which I feel are both fantastic, so far. They have also both recieved quite a significant amount of praise on sites such as Amazon, and have been recommended on math.se before.

If you go to my profile, you can see the type of questions I have asked over the past couple of weeks, which is mainly just what I've gotten to within the first and second chapters of Axler.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://bayesianthink.blogspot.com/2013/09/the-best-books-for-linear-algebra.html#.UjOpwxVx05k) is a list of good books to own in Linear Algebra. Hope that helps